# How do I include a template that includes another template?

Tags: python, django

I have index.html, which loads project/p1.html, which loads project/p2.html. project/p1.html and project/p2.html each load fine on their own, so I know they work correctly. The problem is trying to load project/p1.html into index.html, which has the statement:

```
{% include 'project/p1.html' %}
```

project/p1.html has the statement:

```
{% include 'project/p2.html' %}
```

Loading index.html, I get the error:

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /
Failed lookup for key [objects] in u"[{'params': {}}, {'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7fd3dc0e2410>}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7fd3dc0e2210>, 'user': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x7fd3dc10c790>}, {},......
```

If I delete "{% include 'project/p2.html' %}" from project/p1.html, index.html loads fine and the error message dissapears (but obviously I can't see my content).

How do I resolve this?

EDIT: Heres "project/p2.html":

```
<table class="mytable">

{% for object in objects %}
    <tr class="my_row">
      <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Here's views.py:

```
from models import Mytable
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext

def my_request(request,
    template="project/p1.html",
    page_template="project/p2.html"):
    context = {
        'objects': Mytable.objects.all().order_by('-date'),
        'page_template': page_template,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template
    return render_to_response(template, context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's looking for variables that aren't available to it. Pass in additional context parameters.

`{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}`

EDIT: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs).

Comment: OK...I probably should have stated this in my question: 'project/p1.html' is an infinite scroll page that loads mysql results from p2.html. How do I pass an object to p1.html that isn't hardcoded? ie {% include "project/p2.html" object = object %}?

Comment: thx! I can load p1 with no problems but p2 isn't loading the pagination/infinite scroll. (See my p2.html in my edits). It loads in the html tag for "<table class="mytable">" but it won't load any of the rows. In index.html I have "{% include 'project/p1.html' with objects=objects %}"...Do I need to pass any other parameters?

Comment: I tried p2.html and even took out the pagination...I still can't access the object

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special you need to do to include a template in a template, but you do need to be sure all the variables referenced in all templates are defined in your template context.  Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you may find this helpful: [Django Templates - Changing context for an 'include' template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111555/django-templates-changing-context-for-an-include-template)