# Django Context Processor on {% include %} Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a base-theme.html template with several {% include 'theme-component.html' %} tags.

I also have a context processor that provides a dict of some general items needed by the template - config, menuItems, etc.

The context_processor sends information to the base them when I include them in the base-theme.html directly, but not when I put them in the included template.

For example:

**base-theme.html**

```
    <!doctype html...
         {{ config.site_name }}
         {% include 'menu.html' %}
     </html>
```

***The above works.***

**menu.html**

```
<nav>
  {% for item in menuItems %}
      {{ item }}
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

***This does not work***

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you verified that the ```menuItems``` is actually within the template's context? You can use the Django Debug Toolbar to do this.

Comment: Yes, menuItems works when I place it within the 'base-theme.html'.

Answer (score 0):

To do like that send Menu Item context from your view. Include just includes the template but using it as context you need to send the context

Comment: My understanding is that the context processor makes the variables available globally through the request/response. I thought that the {% include %} would inherit any context passed to the main template - base.html. Is that incorrect?

Comment: No u r right. {% include %} includes your template but to use the context with in your inherited template you should provide context.

Comment: Okay, stupid question, then: how do I include the context to the {% include %}?

Comment: pass the context from your view. Lets say the template you are including has {{some_var}} then pass this context from the view in whose template you are trying to include... {'some_var':some_var}

Comment: But that's the problem; I need the variable available in every template, globally, not just from the single view. I thought that was the purpose of a context processor.

Comment: yeah.. you can write your own middleware and context processor.. that will make your context available globally

Comment: I HAVE written my own context_processor, and, as I said, It works on the base HTML files, but not on {% include %}, so it's not available globally.

Comment: This might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111555/django-templates-changing-context-for-an-include-template